# Angular - Use ngStrictDi with GoogleChart lib

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-visualization

I'm loading googleChart library in an angular application this way (in my app.js) :

```
// load google-chart lib before angularJS to make it work
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['FlexyBeautyApp']);
});
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
```

So, i don't have ng-app directive in my index.html file on body element. I want to use ngStrictDi which has to be placed next this ng-app directive.

Can i write ng-strict-di without ng-app on the body, this will work fine ?

Comment: Did you see ? : 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution seems to be : 
angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['FlexyBeautyApp'],{strictDi:true});

Comment: Exactly ! i saw it but didn't tested it yet... Thank you.